# Maximum Sum Path in a Binary Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to solve this question: https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/description/.

To find maximum sum path is like finding maximum path between any two nodes, that path may or may not pass through the root; except that with max sum path we want to track sum instead of path length.

So, I adapted the diameter of a binary tree's solution to find the maximum sum path.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:

    def height(self, root):
        if root==None:
            return 0

        lh = self.height(root.left)
        rh = self.height(root.right)

        return max(root.val+lh, root.val+rh)

    def maxPathSum(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        if root==None:
            return 0

        lh = self.height(root.left)
        rh = self.height(root.right)

        ld =  self.maxPathSum(root.left)
        rd =  self.maxPathSum(root.right)

        return max(lh+rh+root.val, root.val+ max(ld , rd))
```

My solution is passing 40 test cases before failing.

I am stuck at trying to figure out the correct solution. My solution works for finding the diameter, I just added sum in the return values.

Why is this not a generic solution as i am clearly traversing all the paths and taking appropriate max in return values.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line

```
return max(lh+rh+root.val, root.val+ max(ld , rd))
```

It should be

```
return max(lh+rh+root.val, max(ld , rd))
```

Note that the root node is *not* part of the path for `ld` and `rd`.

Comment: thanks, the code fails for just a tree with one node: -3. the code returns 0.

Comment: @mourinho I didn't realize there could be negative values in the tree. Dealing with negative values makes the problem a whole lot harder. For example, when computing the `height`, it might be advantageous to stop before you reach a leaf node. Which means that you need to consider the path from every node to every other node. Your algorithm is only checking paths from a root to two leaf nodes.

Comment: this is happening because I am not initiazlizing the minimum anywhere so max (-3, 0) is giving 0. Don't really know how to do that in recursion... the current solution, your answer is passing 60 test cases...so I think logic is fine..

Comment: Consider a tree where all the values are negative, except for two positive nodes that happen to be connected to each other. The best path is going to be the path between those two nodes.